# I am trying to add java script in my laravel project but i am finding some errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel

Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020

```
VM966:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at showNeg.js:241
    at XMLHttpRequest.onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandle
```

this is the error i am getting in my project when i am trying to use modal with JavaScript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this is where i am using modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



</div>
</div>



</div>




@endsection

@section('scripts')

<script>

    function handleDelete(id){
        console.log('deleting',id)
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show')
    }
</script>


@endsection
```

i have no idea how to resolve this issue .

[image: here is the error description]

Comment: Share the code where you are trying to use a modal. The error is obvious that the JSON returned to be used is malformed.

Comment: Element.createShadowRoot is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020 i think this is google directory issue i have also shared modal code also..

Comment: i don't know how to remove google directory issue .